# open a query based on many choices

Tags: vba

hello i wrote this code to open a report based on a query
and this query is based on the toggle button

the problem is if i press one toggle button all work
but if i press more than toggle button in the same time it will not give me the right records or it will give me an empty report

this is the code

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tbl_Mouzakarat"

Dim p_7abes As String
Dim p_gharame As String
Dim p_done As String
Dim p_undone As String
Dim p_khoulasa As String
Dim p_mouzakara As String
Dim p_karar As String
Dim p_jaze2e As String
Dim p_lebanese As String
Dim p_foreign As String
Dim p_SQL_criteria As String

p_7abes = Trim(Me!text_7abes & " ")
p_gharame = Trim(Me!text_gharame & " ")
p_done = Trim(Me!text_done & " ")
p_undone = Trim(Me!text_undone & " ")
p_khoulasa = Trim(Me!text_khoulasa & " ")
p_mouzakara = Trim(Me!text_mouzakara & " ")
p_karar = Trim(Me!text_karar & " ")
p_jaze2e = Trim(Me!text_jaze2e & " ")
p_lebanese = Trim(Me!text_lebanese & " ")
p_foreign = Trim(Me!text_lebanese & " ")

If p_7abes <> "" Then
p_SQL_criteria = "[Punish]" & " LIKE '" & p_7abes & "'"
End If
If p_gharame <> "" Then
p_SQL_criteria = "[Punish]" & " LIKE '*" & p_gharame & "*'"
End If
If p_done <> "" Then
p_SQL_criteria = "[Status_Check]" & " LIKE '*" & p_done & "*'"
End If
If p_undone <> "" Then
p_SQL_criteria = "[Status_Check]" & " LIKE '*" & p_undone & "*'"
End If
If p_khoulasa <> "" Then
p_SQL_criteria = "[Type]" & " LIKE '*" & p_khoulasa & "*'"
End If
If p_mouzakara <> "" Then
p_SQL_criteria = "[Type]" & " LIKE '*" & p_mouzakara & "*'"
End If
If p_karar <> "" Then
p_SQL_criteria = "[Type]" & " LIKE '*" & p_karar & "*'"
End If
If p_jaze2e <> "" Then
p_SQL_criteria = "[Type]" & " LIKE '*" & p_jaze2e & "*'"
End If
If p_lebanese <> "" Then
p_SQL_criteria = "[Nationality]" & " LIKE '*" & p_lebanese & "*'"
End If
If p_foreign <> "" Then
p_SQL_criteria = "[Nationality]" & " NOT LIKE '*" & p_foreign & "*'"
End If

If Me.chk7abes.Value = True Then
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_Mouzakarat select * from " & "[qry_Mouzakarat]" & " where " & p_SQL_criteria
End If
If Me.chkGharame.Value = True Then
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_Mouzakarat select * from " & "[qry_Mouzakarat]" & " where " & p_SQL_criteria
End If
If Me.chkDone.Value = True Then
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_Mouzakarat select * from " & "[qry_Mouzakarat]" & " where " & p_SQL_criteria
End If
If Me.ChkUndone.Value = True Then
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_Mouzakarat select * from " & "[qry_Mouzakarat]" & " where " & p_SQL_criteria
End If
If Me.chkKhoulasa.Value = True Then
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_Mouzakarat select * from " & "[qry_Mouzakarat]" & " where " & p_SQL_criteria
End If
If Me.chkMouzakara.Value = True Then
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_Mouzakarat select * from " & "[qry_Mouzakarat]" & " where " & p_SQL_criteria
End If
If Me.chkKarar7abes.Value = True Then
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_Mouzakarat select * from " & "[qry_Mouzakarat]" & " where " & p_SQL_criteria
End If
If Me.chkKararJaze2e.Value = True Then
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_Mouzakarat select * from " & "[qry_Mouzakarat]" & " where " & p_SQL_criteria
End If
DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_Mouzakarat", acViewPreview
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_Printing"
```

will someone check the code please

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting p_SQL_criteria each time then running the same exact query each time no matter how many toggle buttons are pressed.

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_Mouzakarat select * from " & "[qry_Mouzakarat]" & " where " & p_SQL_criteria
```

This is always the exact same SQL statement for each of your `DoCmd` statements.

I'm not really sure how your toggle buttons interact with the parameters you are trying to create so it's hard to suggest solutions, but this is why your having the problem you are having.

Comment: i have textboxes as many as i have toggel buttons every toggle button changer the value of a textbox

so do you have a solution for this code